# Is it possible to measure antenna trap with MFJ225 without help of PC?

Tags: measurement, antenna-analyzer, trap

I have MFJ225 antenna analyzer. I measure coax trap filters by connecting this analyzer to PC and using IG_miniVNA application. That works fine.

But, sometimes I need to make such measurements in portable where I do not have PC available.

A friend has MFJ259 and he uses grid dip coil adapter to successfully measure traps. I tried using his adapter but got no results - meaning no DIP at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a one-turn loop on the analyzer and use that to couple into the trap. There will be a dip in SWR where the trap is resonant.

Here's a picture from the [RigExpert manual](https://www.rigexpert.com/files/manuals/aa3054/aa-30-54-manual.pdf):

[image]

Connect that single-turn loop as if it were an antenna, and do an SWR sweep. The notch is the resonant frequency.

Comment: I tried that but got no dip. Maybe I did something wrong? Will try again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since I resolved mystery, here is short explanation.

I built my own dip adapter exactly as explained by Phil - single loop of wire connected to output of MFJ-225.

However, putting loop at the side of trap (as presented in RigExpert picture) did not work.

**Dip measurement is quite insensitive**, so I had to make sure loop is set at the center of trap length. If not set that way dip may be shallow or not to show at all. I had to make loop with diameter of about 8 cm to be able to measure the biggest trap I have.

**Dip is very sharp**. MFJ-225 must be set to narrow bandwidth or dip simply would not be visible on graph. It seems even when I got dip I could not notice it as I used wider bandwidth for graph.

I found most practical to set bandwidth to 1.18 MHz and step to 1 MHz and scan until dip is noticed. Then switch to narrow bandwidth and fine step to pinpoint exact resonant frequency.

Although graph (ANT-S) looks nicer, it seems to me it is faster to find resonant frequency using plan SWR mode (ANT-G).